# Assembly instructions to switch the CPU to user mode and to kernel mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system

Based on my understanding, when an interrupt is fired, the CPU will switch to kernel mode, and when the interrupt is handled, the operating system will switch the CPU back to user mode.

Now my questions are:

1. How did the operating system switch the CPU to user mode (what is
   the assembly instruction used?).
2. Is there an assembly instruction that switches the CPU to kernel
   mode, or does the switch to kernel mode only happens when an interrupt is fired?

Comment: 1. it switched to a code segment selector with user privilege level using whatever means 2. is the reverse, but the specialized instructions are `syscall` and `sysenter`.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. Which one is used depends on the operating system.

Comment: in general and not specific to an architecture, you would typically have an instruction that is a soft interrupt if you will, by simply executing that instruction the processor would switch modes to a more protected mode based on the design of the processor, and execute code from a known place based on the design of the procesor, and that code is now priveledged, not complicated.  I could call mine syc, have the implementation switch to protected mode and by design start execution from the physical address 0x1000.  Not complicated.

Comment: then what the operating system does with that if it uses it all all is up to the operating system.  often they have a fair amount of freedom.  Windows syscalls dont have to match LInux syscalls for example, but that is architecture dependent, it could be designed into the instruction set that operands cause specific things.

Comment: you cant have an instruction simply switch modes that would allow user applications to just switch to protected mode and cause distruction.  the instruction can be called an interrupt or not as it causes the flow of execution to change to a different address, either the instruction set preserves the state of the machine (it has to preserve some in the same way an interrupt does) or software or a combination.

Comment: so to answer your question, an instruction set that is able to support a protected mode operating system, would need a instruction that does both of the things you are asking about, it is an instruction and it causes an interrupt like response, saves some state and starts execution at a known address (the known address is in a space that the mmu can protect from the application level programs, thus the need to do an interrupt like change to execute somewhere else).

Comment: in addition it is desireable if not required at times to have a timer based interrupt that also switches modes when fired, allowing the operating system to have time slices and/or take control back from an application (otherwise the operating system has to wait for a program to release, think traditional windows, cooperative multitasking I think it is called).

Comment: Unfortunately, the x86 architecture you tagged is too involved to give you a short answer. It boils down to what Jester said but I believe that wouldn't satisfy you as an answer. If you feel like it, read the [Intel SDM 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html) and feel free to come back answering your own question. The protection is described in the first handful of chapters.

Answer (score 2):

> How did the operating system switch the CPU to user mode (what is the assembly instruction used?).

Processors have special return from interrupt instructions. The name of the instruction varies among processors but they all do roughly the same thing. REI, IRET are examples.

> Is there an assembly instruction that switches the CPU to kernel mode, or does the switch to kernel mode only happens when an interrupt is fired?

There are two ways for a process to get into kernel mode: (1) trigger an exception or (2) execute a special instruction. E.g.,

```
    DIVL2 #0, R0
```

Will get you into kernel mode as will

```
 int a = b / 0 ;
```

The instruction for getting into kernel mode varies by processors but examples include CHMK, INT. The i86 family has multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: user->kernel on x86-64 is normally done with the [`syscall`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) instruction.  (And the OS can return with `sysret` instead of `iret`).  32-bit code can use `int` or the more efficient `sysenter`.  Anyway yes, upvoted for pointing out that synchronously triggering an exception is basically how you call into the kernel.